# jq: print array elements if present, print "array is empty" if array is empty, how?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json object that looks like this when empty:

```
{
  "Certificates": [],
  "Chains": [],
  "Keys": []
}
```

Using jq, I am able to print the contents of the above when the Certificates array is not empty, like this:

```
jq -r '. | .Certificates[] | "    - subject: " + .Data.Subject"'
```

What I also need to do is output "no certificates" when the above array is empty.

What modification do I need to make to the jq line above to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [alternative-operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#alternative-operator): `// "no certificates"`:

```
(.Certificates[] | .) // "no certificates"
```

---

Using [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation), your filter will look like:

```
(.Certificates[] | " -subject: \(.Data.Subject)") // "no certificates"
```

---

###### Online JqPlay Demo's:

- ###### [With data](https://jqplay.org/s/atpw7H6XdB5)
- ###### [Without data](https://jqplay.org/s/Q6c4Mp1Gppe)

Comment: It was ment as a placeholder for OP's filter.

Comment: Worked perfectly, gratefully appreciated.